# installing stock android marshmallow on blu r1 hd

Tags: rom-flashing, 6.0-marshmallow

I bought a blu r1 hd and am absolutely loving the phone but i do have one problem. the amazon tweaked android 6.0 is not my favorite. is there a way that i could flash a stock android rom onto the phone? if so, how would i do it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the people from XDA Developers has just come out with a way to root the [Blu R1 HD](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=67890278&postcount=486). And [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=67904010&postcount=4) you have more information about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. You need an Stock AOSP ROM. 
 You will have to root your device and flash the ROM via recovery.

Steps :

  Root your device

  Flash a custom Recovery (TWRP is the most favourite)

  Flash a Stock AOSP ROM and Gapps

[XDA Developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/) is a good resource to look up for !

Comment: You might want to address that there is currently no known root-exploit available and that there isn't any custom recovery nor custom ROM available. So the answer to his question is clearly: **no, not at this moment.** You can link [to this xda-thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/blu-r1-hd-t3418354) for more information and updates regarding root and custom recoverys. Please edit your answer accordingly :)

Comment: @benjaminS This is the only way to achieve this. To remove any system app or bloatware. You'll have to gain root access. And if you don't know how to gain root access, then just sit back and wait for someone to find an exoloit or the user should be happy with the bloatware he's got. If you dont wanna wait. Go on github and download the source and port an AOSP ROM and a recovery for this device. Or just wait for somebody. My answer explains the correct and the only way to do this. Still I'll add your suggestion to it. Thank you !